# how to get the availibility of web service by selenium/java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm in trouble to get status of web service availability by selenium. I making a automate script which login to a portal then visit its web services one by one and set its status. but the issue is to set not availability case either when network down or server issue.

### code

```
 System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "lib/chromedriver"); 
 WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
 try {         
 driver.get("********************");
 driver.manage().window().maximize();
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@id=\"username\"]")).sendKeys("****");
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"password\"]")).sendKeys("*****");
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"loginData\"]/div[6]/span/input")).click();

 //login done here

  driver.get("*****");
  System.out.println("service1 available");

  driver.get("*****");
  System.out.println("service2 available");
```

please help me to get the status this page is loaded/not loaded.

### tried ways

```
   if(driver.findElement(By.xpath("####")).isDisplayed()){
    System.our.println("available");
    }else{
     System.out.println("not available");
    }
```

Comment: try `driver.getTitle()` and check if this title contains known error codes like 400 or 500

Answer (score 0):

> WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver, 1);

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath(*******)));

if(wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(elementXpath))) != null)
{
    **error**
    break;
}
```

Not sure if i understand the question properly. Wouldn't just waiting for an element on the page once it is loaded validate that the page has loaded?

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for presence of element located by: By.xpath: //*[@id="USER_FULL_NAME"]/label (tried for 10 second(s) with 500 MILLISECONDS interval)
 at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.timeoutException(WebDriverWait.java:80)
 at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:232)

Comment: Cannot locate an element using By.xpath

Comment: Please take care to format your code properly. I have rolled it back. You will hopefully see how code is formatted (indented) if you decide to edit.

Answer (score 0):

I have the following 2 suggested ways:

You can use isDisplayed() as below:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("XXXX")).isDisplayed();
```

You can define a method as shown below and call it:

```
public boolean isElementPresent(By by) {
  try {
    driver.findElement(by);
    return true;
  }
catch (org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException e) {
    return false;
  }

}
```

Now, you can do assertion as below to check either the element is present or not:

```
assertTrue(isElementPresent(By.id("XXX")));
```